# Image found even if not on screen

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a basic macro to tell if my lifebar is low but I have a bug in my program where even when lifebar.png isn't on the screen it will still print "I can see it." Can anyone explain why this is happening? Also can someone show me an example where pyautogui locates an image with x confidence and then clicks it?
Thanks.

```
lasthit = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('lifebar.png', confidence=(1))
def new_method(lasthit):
    while True:
        if lasthit is not None:
            print("I can see it.")
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("image not found")
            time.sleep(0.5)
new_method(lasthit)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing `lasthit`?

Comment: According to the pyautogui documentation, that function returns "a generator that yields (left, top, width, height) tuples for where the image is found on the screen."  I would expect that if the image is not found, it returns an empty list, not None.

Comment: Okay so I changed what I had to 
lasthit = pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('lifebar.png', confidence=(0.8))
def new_method(lasthit):
    while True:
        if lasthit is tuple:
            print('lasthit')
            time.sleep(2)
        else:
            print("image not found")
            time.sleep(0.5)
new_method(lasthit)

But now it says image not found even when it is on the screen. What am I doing wrong here?